# Meta tags in twitter are not working. No preview of website is appearing up there

Tags: html, meta-tags

The meta tags are not working on the twitter
how can I solve this problem

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="this is desc">
    
    
    <!-- facebook -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="This is the title">
    <meta property="og:description" content="the desc of the webpage">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://via.placeholder.com/1200X630">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/">

    <!-- twitter -->
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://www.metatags.org/">
    <meta property="twitter:title" content="twitter title">
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1334493324900700161/qUsiG1DS_mini.jpg">
    <meta property="twitter:description" content="twitter this is desc">


    <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Their debugger shows me something like this
[image]

link to the website which i am trying to implement https://jashandeep1659.github.io/meta_tags_in_html/withmeta.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `property` to `name` as shown in the documentation: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/guides/getting-started

```
    <!-- twitter -->
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.metatags.org/">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="twitter title">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1334493324900700161/qUsiG1DS_mini.jpg">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="twitter this is desc">
```

Comment: It still does not work on the debugger's page but It starts working on the main page of twitter where we tweet